# How do click OK button in pop window using selenium python webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here i need to delete some records. when i selected all item and clicked delete button. it has showing pop like "Are you sure want delete this" with OK & no button. then i need to click OK button and deleted the selected item. but i have used below code it hasn't clicking OK button.If anybody know this answer please let me know ..

```
class login(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver= webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://ww.example.com"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def close_all_popups(driver):
    driver.window_handles
    for h in driver.window_handles[1:]:
        driver.switch_to_window(h)
        driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

def test001_login(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(self.base_url +"/")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form-div']/form/input[1]").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form-div']/form/input[1]").send_keys("xxxx")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form-div']/form/input[2]").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form-div']/form/input[2]").send_keys("xxxxx")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form-div']/form/input[3]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='navigation']/li[4]/a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='selectall']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Delete']").click()
    self.close_all_popups()


def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try:self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert.text
    finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't call this method after clicking on delete

```
self.close_alert_and_get_its_text(self)
```

Comment: @ Santosh Sharma :Thanks for replying me. The above code is partially correct.Based on your code i got answer. we are calling the inner class function. like this we have to call : self.close_alert_and_get_its_text(). no need to use self in side argument place.

Comment: @senthil : I don't know Python.. but, by seeing your code I thought of pointing that mistake.. anyway post correct answer in comments that might be useful to another user.